# Como fazer cálculo de tempo entre dois dates?

Tags: php

Tenho um dado do tipo date de um veículo que entrou num estacionamento "2022-06-24 10:55:07", que foi salvo no banco de dados.

Quando esse veículo sai, é pego o date, novamente, ficando por exemplo 2022-06-24 11:30:15.

Dúvida, como posso fazer cálculo de tempo de permanência e salvar no banco?
Na linha "$hourdiff = round((strtotime($entryDateAndTime) - strtotime($departureTime))/3600, 1);" ele pega um número enorme, tipo, 72,5.
OBS: Seria interessante se eu conseguisse salvar no formato 00:00 ou 00:00:00, tanto faz.

Desde já, obrigado pela atenção.

```
<?php
    $departureTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    // SEARCH VEHICLE BY LICENSEPLATE AND STATUS TO GET TICKET INFORMATIONS
    $getVehicleToExitTicket=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM entry_ticket WHERE licensePlate=:licensePlate 
                                            AND statusTicket=:status");
    $getVehicleToExitTicket->bindValue(":licensePlate", $licensePlate);
    $getVehicleToExitTicket->bindValue(":status", $statusForSearch);
    $getVehicleToExitTicket->execute();

    // DATE FROM ENTRY TICKET
    while ($line=$getVehicleToExitTicket->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $parkingName = $line['parkingName'];
        $parkingAddress = $line['parkingAddress'];
        $cnpj = $line['CNPJ'];
        $parkingPhone = $line['parkingPhone'];
        $entryDate = $line['entryDate'];
        $entryTime = $line['entryTime'];

        // CALCULATION OF STAY
        $eD = $entryDate;
        $eT = $entryTime;
        $entryDateAndTime = $entryDate." ".$entryTime;

        $departureTimeP = explode(" ", $departureTime);
        $exitDate = $departureTimeP[0];
        $exitTime = $departureTimeP[1];

        $hourdiff = round((strtotime($entryDateAndTime) - strtotime($departureTime))/3600, 1);
<?
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu faço dessa forma:

```
<?php
$entrada = new DateTime("2022-06-24 10:55:07");
$saida = new DateTime("2022-06-24 11:30:15");
$intervalo = date_diff($entrada,$saida);
echo $intervalo->format('%h:%i:%s');
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
 $date1= date_create($entryDateAndTime);
 $date2= date_create($departureTime);
 $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
 $diff = $diff->format("%H:%I:%S");
 echo $diff
?>
```

> 01:42:21

Comment: Seria legal fornecer detalhes do que tá acontecendo aí.